# Pandas DataFrame - filter, aggregate, and then assign back to original pre-filtered dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way how to take a ecommerce DataFrame, filter out some values, calculate aggregated metrics per each `CustomerID`, and then assign them back to each `CustomerID` to the pre-filtered dataset.

For example - the dummy dataset looks like this:

```
CustomerID   Month  Value
a                1     10
a                2     20
a                3     20
b                1     30
b                2     40
c                1     80
c                2     90
```

I want to filter the dataset on the `Month` column where it equals "1", then calculate quartiles of `Value` per each `CustomerID`, and then add it back to the original dataset for each `CustomerID`.

I know I can do it by calculating the quartiles separately by running groupby, and then using the `quantile` function and then merging back the values to the original dataset, and running if-else commands, but is there a way of piping this request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
df['quantile.25']=df.loc[df.Month==1,'Value'].quantile(0.25)
df
Out[230]: 
  CustomerID  Month  Value  quantile.25
0          a      1     10         20.0
1          a      2     20         20.0
2          a      3     20         20.0
3          b      1     30         20.0
4          b      2     40         20.0
5          c      1     80         20.0
6          c      2     90         20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
s = df.query('Month == 1').groupby('Customer ID')['Month'].quantile()
df['new'] = df['Customer ID'].map(s)
print (df)
  Customer ID  Month  Value  new
0           a      1     10  1.0
1           a      2     20  1.0
2           a      3     20  1.0
3           b      1     30  1.0
4           b      2     40  1.0
5           c      1     80  1.0
6           c      2     90  1.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. First filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
2. Aggregate [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html)
3. Create new column by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)